# How to catch a compile-time exception?

Tags: clojure

Is it possible in Clojure to catch an exception that occurs at compile time? Using try/catch is fine and easy for run-time exceptions, but suppose I have:

```
(defmacro will-throw-at-compile [] (assert false "it threw"))

(try (will-throw-at-compile) (catch Exception e "caught it"))
```

I can't find any way to catch this, the catch never happens. I've tried different types of exception classes as well, doesn't seem to be the problem.

I also thought that since the try above is a run-time call, making a macro to do the try at compile time:

```
(defmacro t [x] (try x (catch Exception e "caught it")))
```

Doesn't work either:

```
(t (will-throw-at-compile))
```

Perhaps can't be done?

Answer (score 3):

You can make it work if the macro handles it's own exception.  Break out the majority of the work of the macro into a function:

```
(defn thrower []
  (throw (Exception. "it threw")))

(defmacro will-throw 
  []
  (try 
    (thrower)
    (catch Exception e (println "caught it")))
  (println "leaving macro"))

(will-throw)
```

Running this code results in:

```
> lein run
caught it
leaving macro
```

The idea is to put most or all of the macro functionality into a regular function, so it can be called & tested outside of the compile-time macro mechanism.  Then you can use regular unit-tests like so:

```
(deftest t-thrower
  (is (thrown? Exception (thrower)))
  (println "t-thrower complete"))

> lein test
caught it
leaving macro

lein test tst.clj.core
t-thrower complete

Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

Comment: I see. I'm trying to figure out a way to easily test that assertions are getting thrown by macros when they are supposed to be, so I would ideally not alter the macros themselves and instead find a way to detect if they emit an exception. I want the macros to in fact throw the assertion, I just want to test it as well.

Comment: Just call macroexpand in your tests, instead of evaluating the macro invocations. Then it happens at runtime and all this is a non-issue.

Comment: The other trick is to put all (or nearly all) of the macro functionality into a plain function that is called by the macro. Then the function can be called & tested outside of the macro context in a regular unit test.