# In Perl 6, how can I print the type of Exceptions thrown, possibly at compile time?

Tags: exception, compilation, raku

I'm trying to [solve this issue](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/833), which mentions that the description of `X::TypeCheck::Splice` exception in [this page is wrong](https://docs.perl6.org/type/X::TypeCheck::Splice). This is the code:

```
use experimental :macros;
CATCH {
    # will definitely catch all the exception 
    default { say .^name, " → ", .Str; }
}

macro a { 'foo'  };
say a;
```

Which I have expanded to include the `CATCH` block. However, an exception gets thrown:

```
===SORRY!===
Too few positionals passed; expected 3 arguments but got 2
```

However, I don't know if it's the correct type since it's not caught by the CATCH block. I have also tried to insert that block into `CHECK` or `BEGIN` phasers, which occur in compile time, to no avail. Any idea?

Apparently, other languages like [clojure let the macro handle its own exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413662/how-to-catch-a-compile-time-exception). That does not seem to work here; inserting the CATCH block inside the macro definition throws a WARNING, and kind of works (would print `Nil`), which probably means it's catching the exception, but still does not print the exception type.

Comment: I think this is why macro's in Perl 6 are still experimental.  And the reason I'm refraining from macro's in Perl 6 so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

running your code through EVAL will throw the compile-time warning at run-time of the eval sub

```
EVAL q/use experimental :macros; macro a { "foo" }; say a/;
CATCH { default { .perl.say } };
# X::AdHoc.new(payload => "Too few positionals passed; expected 3 arguments but got 2")
```

As you can see, at least in this version it's an "untyped" exception. Those can also come from inside the VM, where more nuanced error handling isn't as easy as in Perl 6 or NQP code.

Comment: Does "in this version" that mean the original exception is the same type? It does not make a lot of sense either way...

Comment: Given that that's the way it appears (regardless of what sense it makes) and following timotimo's hint ("Those can also come from inside the VM"), I did a search for "positionals passed" in [rakudo sources](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22positionals+passed%22&type=), [nqp sources](https://github.com/perl6/nqp/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22positionals+passed%22&type=), and [moarvm sources](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22positionals+passed%22&type=). As you can see, it's ad hoc (untyped) in all three. Little point in fixing unless all three?